# Python popen gives me an empty byte string in stderr

Tags: python, popen

I'm running a subprocess using Popen. In my tuple results, I get `(None, b'')`.

My code:

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(cmd,\
         stdout=None,\
         stderr=subprocess.PIPE,\
         env=os.environ,\
         shell=True)
```

I'm curious as to what `b''` is. Looking at the docs, it's just the resulting error, but what kind of error is an empty byte string?

Comment: It means your command never actually wrote any error messages.

Comment: It means there was no error and `stderr` was empty.

Comment: Thanks for the info! My program needs a `(None ,None)` value in order to continue running. If there was actually no error, is there a clean way to convert `b''` to `None`?

Comment: `if err = '': err = None` where `err` is what you read from the `stderr` pipe.